# Is there an way draw circle with radius in meters in mapbox?

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I'm trying to draw circle with 500meters radius around user current location in mapbox. When I use the code I provided below it draws a big circle also it is not tilting with map.

```
CircleManager circleManager = new CircleManager(mapView, mapboxMap, style);
CircleOptions options = new CircleOptions();
options.withLatLng(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
options.withCircleRadius(500f);
options.withCircleOpacity(0.5f);
options.withCircleColor(ColorUtils.colorToRgbaString(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue2)));

circleManager.create(options);
```

I expect my app work like this:
[image: Expected Results]

But currently I'm having this issue:
[image]

**UPDATED**

I'm able to draw circle with accurate coordinates but I want this circle to move with my location. Circle is added when map is clicked but cannot add circle when calling this from location change listener.

```
private void moveRing(Point centerPoint) {
    if (mapboxMap.getStyle() != null) {
        Style style = mapboxMap.getStyle();

        // Use Turf to calculate the coordinates for the outer ring of the final Polygon
        Polygon outerCirclePolygon = getTurfPolygon(OUTER_CIRCLE_MILE_RADIUS, centerPoint);

        GeoJsonSource outerCircleSource = source;

        if (outerCircleSource != null) {
            outerCircleSource.setGeoJson(Polygon.fromLngLats(outerCirclePolygon.coordinates()));
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CircleManager itself doesn't support this feature but you can use Turf from [mapbox-java](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/testapp/activity/turf/PhysicalUnitCircleActivity.kt#L47) to convert the required properties to Polygon/Fill:

```
  /**
   * Takes a {@link Point} and calculates the circle polygon given a radius in degrees, radians,
   * miles, or kilometers; and steps for precision. This uses the {@link #DEFAULT_STEPS} and
   * {@link TurfConstants#UNIT_DEFAULT} values.
   *
   * @param center a {@link Point} which the circle will center around
   * @param radius the radius of the circle
   * @return a {@link Polygon} which represents the newly created circle
   * @since 3.0.0
   */
  public static Polygon circle(@NonNull Point center, double radius) {
    return circle(center, radius, 64, TurfConstants.UNIT_DEFAULT);
  }
```

You can use this geometry in combination with the FillManager from the annotation-plugin.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-java/blob/master/services-turf/src/main/java/com/mapbox/turf/TurfTransformation.java#L66. Pass through 360 for the # of steps for the best looking circle.

This is a Java port of http://turfjs.org/docs/#circle.

Comment: @mian-asad-ali, see https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/android-location-listening. 

This guide shows that you can run code when the device location updates. `onSuccess()` fires when the location changes. Inside of `onSuccess()` is where you could move the circle.